# WIX MSI: copying long file names or files which has long file path

Tags: wix, copy, windows-installer, long-filenames

I created MSI using WIX. It contains few files which has long path (more than 248 characters) and file name (more than 260 characters, including file path + file name). while installing this MSI package into my computer it is throwing error "Error writing file...... Verify you have access to that file". 
This is throwing due to long file. Please suggest any solutions.

Comment: That's a Windows limitation AFAIK, not WiX.

Comment: Is the MSI compressed or uncompressed?

Comment: Chris, does it make a difference? Is MSI able to install to longer paths, if the .cabs are inside?- I don't know it, so I am interested too.

Comment: I was just wondering if the file path too long was happening on the source path or the dest path.  A compressed MSI would rule out source path.

Comment: Christopher or Philm, file path too long in destination path.

Comment: PhilDW, yes it is the same problem in Windows also, do you we have any solution for this if use WIX